# Dockerコンテナ内からapt-getコマンドエラー解決方法に関して

Tags: docker, network

ubuntu latest イメージから生成したコンテナから必要なライブラリ等をインストールするため　リポジトリのアップデートを試みたところ下記のエラーが出ます。

```
root@59eec8e98b0b:/# apt-get update
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease        
  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                  
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Reading package lists... Done        
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-backports/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

システム仕様は下記の通りです。

OS: Ubuntu　18.04.1　LTS
Docker: 18.06.1-ce
インターネット　←→　社内LAN　←→　ルーター（プライベートアドレス）　←→　PC

dockerホスト（Ubuntu　OS)上では、問題なく外部と繫がります。

dockerホスト上でのネットワークアダプタの設定は下記の通りで、Dockerコンテナから外部へのアクセスに関するネット情報とあわせて、特段問題がないように見えます。

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp9s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e0:db:55:a9:3f:24 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.11.2/24 brd 192.168.11.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp9s0
       valid_lft 169423sec preferred_lft 169423sec
    inet6 fe80::e52:b647:3b9e:d5c6/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: docker0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 02:42:6d:9f:87:ae brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:6dff:fe9f:87ae/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
31: veth70e27c5@if30: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master docker0 state UP group default 
    link/ether 2a:6b:4e:c4:8f:44 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet6 fe80::286b:4eff:fec4:8f44/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

ブリッジの設定は下記の通りです。

```
docker0     8000.02426d9f87ae   no      veth70e27c5
```

コンテナ内からpingを実行しようとしたところ、　command not found コンテナ側からホストへのアクセス確認もできません。

ちなみに、CentOSでは、pingはルータ下のアドレスには届くのですが、ルータ外のアドレスにはアクセス不可能なようです。

以上、原因の分かる方がおられましたら、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: "ちなみに"で出てきたCentOSは実マシン、Dockerイメージのどちらでしょうか？

Comment: Dockerイメージになります。

Comment: なんとなくDockerのDNS周りが怪しい気がします。一度、その辺りをお調べになってみてはどうでしょうか。

Comment: コメント有難うございます。DockerホストからDockerコンテナのipアドレス（172.17.*.*）には　pingで通信を確認しています。pingがインストール済みのCentOSイメージのDockerコンテナ内からホストのip(192.168.*.*）への通信も確認していることから、コメントの意味はDNSサーバーとの通信が怪しいということと理解しました。ただ、ネットワークの設定等に関しては素人なので、ネット情報を頼りに関係する対応策として、/etc/default/docker　のファイル内の　#DOCKER_OPTS="--dns 8.8.8.8 --dns 8.8.4.4"　コメントをを外してみましたが、解決しませんでした。iptablesの設定は、知識がないのでデフォルトのままです。

Comment: 原因は明確では有りませんが、なんとか次のような経緯で対処できました。Dockerホストでifconfigにより、表示されるdocker0(仮想ブリッジ）とenp9s0（物理ネットワーク　NIC）を改めて確認したところ、MACアドレスが異なっていました。これでは、コンテナから外部へ通信ができないと思い、dockerのrunコマンドのオプションで、--mac-address=NICのMACアドレスを指定しコンテナを作成の後、コンテナ内でapt-get をしましたが、やはり、名前解決ができていないエラーコメントが出ました。次に、run コマンドのオプションで MACアドレスの指定は行わず、適当ですが、--dns=Docker搭載のPCが接続されているルータのipアドレス　にしたところ、コンテナ内でのapt-getが実行できました。ただ、/etc/default/docker　のdnsのアドレス指定に、このアドレスを追加したものの、変わらず同じエラーが出ています。　以上、回りくどい表現ですが、何故解決したかよく理解できてません。もし、分かる方がおられましたら、ご教授よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 更に他のサイト情報を調べたましたところ、ようやく原因と解決方法が分かりました。「Docker ドキュメント日本語化プロジェクト　ユーザ定義ネットワーク用の内部 DNS サーバ」　のページに記載されていました。具体的には、コンテナ作成時にDockerを使用するネットワーク環境に合せて、オプションでDNSサーバーのアドレス指定をすること。生成されたコンテナ内の　/etc/resolv.conf　に、そのアドレスが反映されていることが確認できます。また、別サイトに　/etc/default/docker　が設定が有効になっていないのは、あるバージョン以降Ubuntuでは、systemd起動により、/etc/default/docker　を読みにいかないということが書かれてありました。　以上、コメントを頂いた方、並びに当質問をご検討いただいた方　有難うございました。

Comment: @pupupu 解決した場合には是非その情報を「個別の回答」として投稿してもらうと、同じ問題で困った人の参考になるかと思います (スタック・オーバーフローでは自己回答も歓迎されます)。

Comment: cubick様　コメント有難うございます。　回答させていただきますが、しばらくお待ち下さい。

Answer (score 3):

今回のエラーの原因は、ローカルエリアネットワークに接続したPC上のDockerコンテナから外部のインターネット上のコンテンツや資源にアクセスする場合に、適切なDNSサーバーにアクセスできないことであった。
　DNSサーバーにアクセスする一つの方法として、dockerコンテナ起動時のrunコマンドのオプション　（書式　--dns=DNSサーバーのIPアドレス）でアドレスを指定することであると、あるサイト情報に記載されていた。これに従い、今回の場合はPCの接続先であるルータ上にローカルなDNSサーバーが設定されていたので、そのルータのIPアドレスを指定することで解決した。